# CF8 vs. CF10: local scope declared in parent not visible in child functions

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I have quite a bit of code written for ColdFusion 8 that is failing in ColdFusion 10.  I realize that CF9 and later handles the "Local" scope differently than previous. My problem is that I've coded functions to extend each, in the sense that child instances inherit variables from the parent. But just to be clear exactly what I mean, let me give you an example of what was working and how it's failing in CF10.

Take two CFCs, a Child CFC that extends the Parent CFC:

```
<!--- Parent.cfc --->
<cfcomponent displayname="Parent">

    <cffunction name="SomeFunction" output="yes">
        <cfset local.parent_val = "Declared in parent instance">
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>



<!--- Child.cfc --->
<cfcomponent displayname="Child" extends="Parent">
    <cffunction name="SomeFunction" output="yes">
    <cfset local.child_val = "Declared in child instance">

    <!--- The following "super" call will instantiate the "parent_val" variable
    from within the parent CFC's version of this function... but only in CF8? --->
    <cfset Super.SomeFunction() />

    <p>#local.child_val#</p>
    <p>#local.parent_val#</p>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Invoked as:

```
<cfset ChildCFC = CreateObject("component","Child") />
<cfoutput>#ChildCFC.SomeFunction()#</cfoutput>
```

In CF8 I get:

`Declared in child instance
Declared in parent instance`

In CF10 I get:

`Declared in child instance
[error dump showing "Element PARENT_VAL is undefined in LOCAL."]`

As you can see, in CF10, even after calling the parent version of the function (via "super") the local variable declared in the parent is not accessible in the child as it was under CF8.

So, my question is this: Is there any hope of recovering the architecture as designed in the examples above?  If not, is there an easy migration trick that I'm missing?

A lot of my code expects a child-owned function to be able to "see" variables declared in the parent by use of the SUPER call (as in the example above). For those that faced this transition from CF8 to current, I'd appreciate your thoughts and suggestions here.

Comment: Did you use `LOCAL` in CF 8 with the `var` keyword?

Comment: @Bardware - My *guess* would be no. So "local" is actually stored in the `variables` scope, and hence visible to the child component.

Comment: @Bardware: Nope. The code is just as you see above. In the Parent.SomeFunction() it uses "Local" and CF8 didn't have a problem making that available to child instances. So while I know that "var" in C8 equals "Local" in CF10, my challenge is how to (hopefully easily) keep that same variable visibility as I was using in CF8.

Comment: Yeah, as Henry points out in his answer, what you are claiming were local variables in your CF8 code actually *weren't* "local" in the sense you were thinking they were; whereas in CF9+ they would be. You need to redeisgn and rewrite your code to use your local variables properly.

Comment: @AdamCameron: Do you know of any problem with doing this?... <cfset Local = SUPER.SomeFunction() /> ... in order to establish a struct from a parent/base CFC definition?

Comment: That's a new question, so raise it accordingly. Provide an example of what you're trying and what the end came is, etc. We'll need more space to answer it than that which a comment on an existing question affords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your CF8 SomeFunction() in Parent.cfc

```
local.parent_val = blah // sets to variables.local.parent_val, dies with object
```

In your CF9 SomeFunction() in Parent.cfc

```
local.parent_val = blah // eqv to var parent_val, dies right after function quits
```

Your code in CF8 was wrong to begin with.  If it was meant to be local to the function, it should have had a `var local = {}` on the very first line of the function.  Then the behavior wouldn't have changed in CF9+.

If your existing code base has not ran into thread-safety issue, then I think you can rename `local.` to `variables.` for variables that you expect to live on with the object and accessible later by the child.

Comment: You nailed it. By renaming `Local.` to `Variables.` the variables declared in the base (parent) are available in the inherited (child) function.  The original design was faulty, even though it "worked" under CF8. What I was doing, without realizing it, was instantiating a variable without the "var" and taking advantage of its visibility. Fortunately I never ran into any problem traceable to this design, but I've already re-coded all occurrences. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed by Henry, your Local in CF8 was in fact a structure in Variables scope, until, if you forgot to mention something. Normally in those CF8 days, dev would set LOCAL as var scoped with

```
<cfset var Local={}>
```

and then anything under it will always be in var scope. If that was the case with your code and it is not working anymore (sorry can not check on that) then you are in for some rough time. But if it it was just exactly like you mentioned then it is in Variables scope already and changing

```
<cfset local.parent_val = "Declared in parent instance">
```

to

```
<cfset Variables.parent_val = "Declared in parent instance">
```

should work. If it has not created any thread issue in CF8, I do not see any reason happening that in CF10 for your specific case (normally this creates issues).
Personally I think adding LOCAL scope was bad idea when we already had VAR scope. I know senior community devs asked for it, but it was bad idea.